# How to add tree-sitter python grammar to tree-sitter?

Tags: python, parsing, body-parser, treesitter

I am not accustomed to build files or those stuff. Please guid me through the https://pypi.org/project/tree-sitter/
Can you please let me know how to add the python grammar.

I tried to follow the instructions, but I am not getting it.